# Controller in Service in radzen will not trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, blazor, blazor-webassembly

we have problem Calling Controller in Service in radzen. we create the controller but we can't load this controller when we want to call it.

this is my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing;
using PiroozApp.Data;
using PiroozApp.Models.PiroozDb;

namespace PiroozApp.Server.Controllers.Pirooz
{
    [ODataRoutePrefix("odata/PiroozDb/Tests")]
    [Route("mvc/odata/PiroozDb/Tests")]
    public partial class TestsController : ODataController
    {
        private PiroozDbContext context;

        public TestsController(PiroozDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        // GET /odata/PiroozDb/Tests
        [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 10, MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 10, MaxNodeCount = 1000)]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Station> GetStations()
        {
            var items = context.Stations.AsQueryable<Station>();
            OnStationsRead(ref items);

            return items;
        }

        partial void OnStationsRead(ref IQueryable<Station> items);
    }
}
```

this is my service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Radzen;
using PiroozApp.Models.PiroozDb;

namespace PiroozApp
{
    public partial class StationsService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private readonly Uri baseUri;
        private readonly NavigationManager navigationManager;
        public StationsService(NavigationManager navigationManager, HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;

            this.navigationManager = navigationManager;
            this.baseUri = new Uri($"{navigationManager.BaseUri}odata/PiroozDb/");
        }



        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExportStationsToExcel(Query query = null, string fileName = null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"export/piroozdb/stations/excel(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')") : $"export/piroozdb/stations/excel(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')", true);
        }

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExportStationsToCSV(Query query = null, string fileName = null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"export/piroozdb/stations/csv(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')") : $"export/piroozdb/stations/csv(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')", true);
        }
        partial void OnGetStations(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage);


        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ODataServiceResult<Station>> GetStations(string filter = default(string), string orderby = default(string), string expand = default(string), int? top = default(int?), int? skip = default(int?), bool? count = default(bool?), string format = default(string))
        {
            var uri = new Uri(baseUri, $"Tests");
            uri = uri.GetODataUri(filter: filter, top: top, skip: skip, orderby: orderby, expand: expand, select: null, count: count);

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

            OnGetStations(httpRequestMessage);

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            return await response.ReadAsync<ODataServiceResult<Station>>();
        }
```

we can't connect from service to controller.
Warning: The Radzen Has Converted The Sources To JASON in a Layer Named Meta.

P.S: I used "ControllerBase" instead "Controller". problem didn't solved.
P.S 2: I don't know why whole source is turned to json.

it means if we want to call the controller form service. based on this code:

```
 protected async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Grid0LoadData(LoadDataArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                var piroozDbGetStationsResult = await StationsService.GetStations(filter:$@"(contains(StationName,""{search}"") or contains(Descriptions,""{search}"")) and {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Filter)? "true" : args.Filter)}", orderby:$"{args.OrderBy}", expand:$"Line", top:args.Top, skip:args.Skip, count:args.Top != null && args.Skip != null);
                getStationsResult = piroozDbGetStationsResult.Value.AsODataEnumerable();

                getStationsCount = piroozDbGetStationsResult.Count;
            }
            catch (System.Exception piroozDbGetStationsException)
            {
                NotificationService.Notify(new NotificationMessage(){ Severity = NotificationSeverity.Error,Summary = $"Error",Detail = $"Unable to load Stations" });
            }
        }
```

the parameter we define in this method returns null value because cant find the controller. so it shows Unable to load Stations.

Comment: "we can't connect" is not very informative. Any error messages, what does (not) happen?

Comment: [edit] the question when you have extra information.

Comment: Did you find the issue? I'm having a problem now also.. where it gets stuck at `ReadAsync<ODataServiceResult<TEntity>>()`